# ¿Cómo establecer la raíz de mi instalación de Java para Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

Intento descaragar HBase con [el siguiente vinculo de tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_installation.htm). Tuve que installar Hadoop. Lo hice con [el siguiente tutorial de hadoop.apache.org](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html). Después de desempacar la distribución Hadoop descargada tuve que editar el archivo etc / hadoop / hadoop-env.sh para definir algunos parámetros de la siguiente manera :

```
  # set to the root of your Java installation
  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
```

Sin embargo, cuando probé el comando `bin/hadoop` me contesto el terminal :

```
:~/hadoop-3.0.0-beta1$ bin/hadoop
ERROR: JAVA_HOME /usr/java/latest does not exist.
```

Todavia cuando preguntolo la version de java me dice :

```
:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso suelo crear un fichero profile que contiene la ruta al JDK que quieres usar, por ejemplo el siguiente (créalo como root, en /etc/profile.d/java.sh)

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Si no tienes permisos como root, puedes añadirlo al final de tus ficheros de configuración de usuario (el .bashrc que tienes en tu $HOME que se carga cuando haces login).